# Remote Desktop refusing connections

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I am running into a unique situation with Remote Desktop that I have never seen before. I have 3 PC's, two laptops and 1 desktop, all running Win 7 64B retail. Under normal circumstances I use the desktop as the hub of my work and remote desktop into the laptops when I need.
Last night I installed a MS Update that included a driver update from my MS Wireless keyboard. After the necessary reboot of that, Remote Desktop from my desktop to any of the laptops has completely stopped working.

All the PC's are connected into the same switch that is connected to the internet. I can ping back and forth from the desktop to the laptop successfully. I can Remote desktop between the two laptops successfully. However, no matter what I do I can't Remote Desktop from the desktop to anything. I have tried giving all the PC's new names, creating a different workgroup and adding them to that, creating a new Admin account on the desktop and trying that. All with no success.

Comment: Check the firewall settings on your desktop machine.

Comment: Have you tried a System Restore yet?  How about uninstalling the updates you suspect?

Comment: Tried uninstalling the MS keyboard update, but I couldn't find it in the update list.

Comment: As for the firewall settings.  I can Remote desktop FROM the laptops to the desktop, but just not from Desktop to the laptops

Comment: I had this happen to me once - somehow Windows 7 had decided that the network I connected to (same home network as always) was for some reason now a PUBLIC network vs. a home/work network, and switched to THAT set of firewall rules.

Comment: As a trouble shooting step, I just got done disabling the firewall on both the desktop and the laptop.  Still no success.

Comment: @Doug - Have you rolled back the system using a restore point?

Comment: I don't have a restore point to go back to.

Answer (score 0):

If you just enter the machine name without the id\pw, does remote desktop successfully get to the machine and then prompt you for an id\pw *OR* is remote desktop not able to find and\or connect to the target machine?